Child component need to re render after value changes in parent component
I have 3 components. Grand Parent --> Parent --> Child.  
When ever data changed in Child LWC I need to Re-render the Child LWC which is inside Parent LWC.
I have tried GET SET methods also. But that did not do the calculations after rendering for the first time.
Here Child LWC using many times in Parent LWC. Initial on load calculations happeneing correctly. But When I do some changes in Input number or Checkbox change - am calling onchange={calculateVal} OR onchange={changeToggle} 
Then calling performCalculaton() function to do all math logic.  
From Child.JS - invoking reflectedvaluechange event to pass to Parent.HTML. 
In Parent.JS calling **populatetotalEngineering** function to calculate - totalPrice.

Here Problem is in Sales Area section2  If I make any changes, It should also re- render Sales Area section1 component - so that all math calculations will be rendered based on input totalPrice.
Parent.html 
<template>
   <template if:true={isloading}>
      <div class="exampleHolder">
         <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
      </div>
   </template>
   <div class="slds-box" style="width: 98.5%;">
      <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-title_bold">Sales Area section1</div>
      <template if:true={loadsalesarea}>
         <template for:each={accountdata} for:item="data">
            <template if:true={data.enableSalesPrice}>
               <c-child key={data.id} field-label={data.fieldLabel} header-label={data.headerLabel}
                  onreflectedvaluechange={populatetotalEngineering} total-price ={totalPrice} input-value={data.inputValue} input-checkbox={data.inputCheckbox} 
                  transfter-price={transfterPrice}  > </c-child>
            </template>
         </template>
      </template>
   </div>
   
   <div class="slds-box">
       <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-title_bold">Sales Area section2 </div>
            <template for:each={accountdata} for:item="data">
               <template if:true={data.enableSalesGeneral}>
                  <c-child key={data.id} field-label={data.fieldLabel} header-label={data.headerLabel}
                  onreflectedvaluechange={populatetotalEngineering}  total-price = {totalPrice} input-value={data.inputValue} input-checkbox={data.inputCheckbox} 
                  transfter-price={transfterPrice}  > </c-child>
               </template>
            </template>
        </div>
</template>


Parent.JS
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';

import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class parent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
   
    @api totalcalculatedvalue;
    @track error;
    @track loadchildcomp = false;
    @track loadsalesarea = false;
    @track executiondone = false;
    accountRecord = {};
    fieldMapping = {};

    connectedCallback() {
        this.source = 'default';
        const fieldMappingPairs = [
             ['field1', 'field_Percentage1-field_value1'],
            ['field2', 'field_Percentage2-field_value2'],
            ];
        this.fieldMapping = new Map(fieldMappingPairs);

    }
   
    populatetotalEngineering(event) {

        this.accountRecord[event.detail.sourcefield] = event.detail.selectedvalue;
        this.accountRecord[this.fieldMapping.get(event.detail.sourcefield).split('-')[0]] = event.detail.checkboxselected;
        this.accountRecord[this.fieldMapping.get(event.detail.sourcefield).split('-')[1]] = event.detail.inputentered;

        if (this.objectData.length > 0) {
            if (!this.keyExists(this.objectData, 'fieldname', event.detail.sourcefield)) {
                var newObjectData = {
                    fieldname: event.detail.sourcefield,
                    value: event.detail.selectedvalue
                };
                this.objectData.push(newObjectData);

            } else {
                this.objectData.forEach((element, index) => {
                    if (element.fieldname == event.detail.sourcefield) {
                        element.value = event.detail.selectedvalue;
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            var newObjectData = {
                fieldname: event.detail.sourcefield,
                value: event.detail.selectedvalue
            };
            this.objectData.push(newObjectData);
        }
      
        this.totalEngineeringCost = 0;
        
        this.objectData.forEach((element, index) => {

            if ((element.fieldname == "field1" && typeof this.objectData[index].value == "number" && this.objectData[index].value >= 0) ) {
                this.field1Value = this.objectData[index].value + this.field1Value;
            }
             if ((element.fieldname == "field2" && typeof this.objectData[index].value == "number" && this.objectData[index].value >= 0) ) {
                this.field2Value = this.objectData[index].value + this.field2Value;
            }
        
        });
        this.performwholecalculations();
    }

     performwholecalculations() {
        this.loadsalesarea = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());

        this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice1 + this.totalPrice2;
        if (this.executiondone) {
          
           this.recal();
        }
         this.loadsalesarea = true;
    }
    
   get fullCostval (){
       return this.totalPrice;
    }

    recal() {
        // Creates the event with the data.
        const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("resetvalue", {
            detail: {
                totalPrice: this.totalPrice,
                callchild: true
            }
        });
        // Dispatches the event.
        this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
    }
    keyExists(array, property, key) {
        return array.some(item => item[property] === key);
    }
}


child.HTML
<template>
   <div data-id="myDiv" class="slds-grid" style={yellowstyle}>
      <div class="slds-size_4-of-8" style="font-weight:600;">
         <div class={label1Style}>
            <b> {fieldLabel} </b>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-form-element">
         <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Apply Percentage</span>
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-15" onchange={changeToggle} checked ={inputCheckbox} aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-15" />
         <span id="checkbox-toggle-15" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container">
         <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-size_1-of-8">
         <div class="slds-p-top--x-small">
            <lightning-input type="number" class="inputCmp" step=".01" variant="label-hidden"
               value={inputValue} onchange={calculateVal}>
            </lightning-input>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <div class="slds-text-align_center slds-p-around--xx-small slds-m-around_x-small slds-size_1-of-8"
            style={paddingleftstyle}>
            <lightning-formatted-number value={reflectedValue}>
            </lightning-formatted-number>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>


Child.JS
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class child extends LightningElement {
@api totalcostfromMain;
@api transfterPrice;
@api totalPrice;
@api originalTransferprice;

// TRIED GET SET ALSO. BUT DID NOT WORK.
   /* @api set fullCost1(value) {
        alert('New value setting '+value);
        this.performCalculaton();
        this.totalPrice = [...value];
    }
    get fullCost1() {
        return this.totalPrice;
    }  */

changeToggle(event) {   
    this.expression = event.target.checked;
    this.inputCheckbox = event.target.checked;
    this.performCalculaton();
}


calculateVal(event) {
    this.inputValue = parseFloat(event.target.value);
    this.performCalculaton();
}

performCalculaton() { 
    this.reflectedValue = this.inputCheckbox ? this.transfterPrice / 100 * this.inputValue : this.inputValue;
    if (this.fieldLabel == 'fied1') {
      
        if(this.totalPrice){
                this.reflectedValue = (this.inputCheckbox ? this.totalPrice / 100 * this.inputValue : this.inputValue) + this.totalPrice;
               
        }
       }
    if (this.fieldLabel == 'field2') {
            this.reflectedValue = this.inputCheckbox ? this.originalprice / 100 * this.inputValue : this.inputValue;
       
    } 
    // Creates the event with the data.
    const selectedEvent = new CustomEvent("reflectedvaluechange", {
        detail: {
            selectedvalue: this.reflectedValue,
            sourcefield: this.headerLabel,
            checkboxselected: this.inputCheckbox,
            inputentered: this.inputValue
        } 
    });
    // Dispatches the event.
    this.dispatchEvent(selectedEvent);
}
}

